# How to rotate libGDX particle to face the direction of movement

Tags: libgdx, particles

I'm creating spark particle effect so I created simple horizontal spark texture.

[image: spark]

Here is what I currently have

[image]

If I change rotation property, I get this

[image]

But i want to rotate particle to face the direction of movement. How can I achieve it?

I use libGDX Particle Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a Vector2 for your motion (or an x-speed and a y-speed variable), you just need to do a little trigonometry. To find the angle of travel, you take the arctangent of the y-speed divided by the x-speed. Let's call your motion vector "velocity." You can derive the angle by taking atan(velocity.y/velocity.x).

Comment: Yeah, but I use libGDX Particle Editor, not my own particles. And libgdx Vector2 has angle() method.

Answer (score 0):

It works with "aligned" option, but you need to set only one value in angle settings chart.

[image]